# Problem for number theory

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

Here it is:

$c , n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$

$c= 1 x_1 + 2 x_2 + \ldots + n x_n$

How many solutions $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ are there?

I do not know number theory. However, i think that what I am looking at is a number theory problem. It is a counting problem that arises from a statistical physics toy model i am working on.

The solution may be trivial and in textbooks or it could be a hard problem. I don't know that is why i am asking, for guidance on what kind of set of skills deals with these things. Thanks anyone. mario

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^nkx_k = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^nx_k$ this might help

Comment: thanks for that small identity, it may help, i did not clarify that the x's can be zero too it is corrected now

Comment: That's the number of integer partitions of $c$ with parts $\le n$.

Comment: yes that is correct. thanks at least now i can use mathematica function IntegerPartitions[c,n,Range[n]] to get the explicit answer. May i ask if there is an analytical formula or approximation for this? The wikipedia page is not very helpful on this. I only need the number of them or the approximate number, not the actual partitions.

Comment: There is not.  There is a vast literature of investigation of this function in both mathematics and physics.  There is a lot known, especially asymptotically, but no simple formula to express it.

Comment: ok thanks. if there are results in the large number limit that could be of use to me, i 'll have to do some digging to find that.